# Javascript Drop Down Menu Currency Converter

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, currency

Hello everyone I need you guys help with this
It's suppose to convert the value you entered after you choose an option and click convert.

HTML CODE:/(I'm not sure how to use drop down menus with java script)

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form>
    <select name="converts" id="Selection">
    <option>Chose Option</option>
     <option value="1" >Currency 1 to Currency2</option>
     <option value="2" >Currency 2 to Currency1</option>
    </select>
     <br><br>
    Value <input type="text" id="value"><br>
    Conversion <input type="text" id="conversion"><br><br>

    <input type="Button" onclick="Conversion()" value="Convert">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function Conversion() 
   {
   var val = document.getElementById ("value").value;
   var madeSelection =  document.getElementById ("Selection").value;

    if(madeSelection==1( var ans= +value * 1.37); )){
    if(madeSelection==2 ( var ans= +value * 1.30; )){

                    }
                }

    conversion.value = ans;
    }
    </script>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems that are causing this to be non-functional:

You declare a variable called `val` that you are not using. Everywhere else in your code, it is called `value`.

```
var val = document.getElementById ("value").value;
```

Older browsers may not deal with a `value` property of a `select` element

```
var madeSelection =  document.getElementById ("Selection").value;
```

Your `if` statements are malformed (and nested for some reason), and some of the operations are weird.

```
if(madeSelection==1( var ans= +value( 0.37); )){
if(madeSelection==2 ( var ans= +value * 0.30; )){
...
```

When properly formatted, your code is:

```
if (madeSelection == 1(var ans = +value(0.37);)) {
    if (madeSelection == 2(var ans = +value * 0.30;)) {
        if (madeSelection == 3(var ans = +value * 2.70;)) {
            if (madeSelection == 4(var ans = +value * 0.80;)) {
                if (madeSelection == 5(var ans = +value * 3.38;)) {
                    if (madeSelection == 6(var ans = +value * 1.25;)) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When more properly written, it should be:

```
if (madeSelection == 1) {
    var ans = +value(0.37);
}
if (madeSelection == 2) {
    var ans = +value * 0.30;
}
if (madeSelection == 3) {
    var ans = +value * 2.70;
}
if (madeSelection == 4) {
    var ans = +value * 0.80;
}
if (madeSelection == 5) {
    var ans = +value * 3.38;
}
if (madeSelection == 6) {
    var ans = +value * 1.25;
}
```

although:

- the `ans` variable, along with all of your other variables should be declared at the top of the function (because that's where they're actually declared anyway, look up variable hoisting).
- I'm not sure why you're prefixing the righthand assigment with the `+`.
- `value` is not a function, but you're apparently attempting to use it as one if `madeSelection == 1`.

Finally, you're referencing a variable called `conversion` which has not been defined. This will still probably work as you have an input with an `id` of `conversion` and most (but not all) browsers will store the `id` as a global variable pointing to the element.

Also, when you have many `if` statements, you may wan't to consider using a `switch` statement instead.

All together, it should look more like this:

```js
function Conversion() {
    var value = document.getElementById("value").value,
        conversion = document.getElementById("conversion"),
        madeSelection = document.getElementById("Selection"), // get the select
        selection = madeSelection.options[madeSelection.selectedIndex].value, // get the selected option
        ans = 0;
    value = parseFloat(value);
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        switch (selection) {
            case "6":
                ans = value * 1.25;
                break;
            case "5":
                ans = value * 3.38;
                break;
            case "4":
                ans = value * 0.8;
                break;
            case "3":
                ans = value * 2.7;
                break;
            case "2":
                ans = value * 0.3;
                break;
            case "1":
                ans = value * 0.37;
                break;
            default:
                ans = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    conversion.value = ans;
}
```

```html
<select name="converts" id="Selection">
    <option>Choose Option</option>
    <option value="1" >EC to US</option>
    <option value="2" >EC to Euro</option>
    <option value="3" >US to EC</option>
    <option value="4" >US to Euro</option>
    <option value="5" >Euro to EC</option>
    <option value="6" >Euro to US</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="value">Value</label>
<input type="text" id="value"><br>
<label for="conversion">Conversion</label>
<input type="text" id="conversion"><br><br>
<input type="Button" onclick="Conversion()" value="Convert">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
function Conversion() {
    var val = document.getElementById("value").value,
    madeSelection = document.getElementById("Selection").value,
    ans

    if (madeSelection == 1) ans = val * 0.37;
    if (madeSelection == 2) ans = val * 0.30;
    if (madeSelection == 3) ans = val * 2.70;
    if (madeSelection == 4) ans = val * 0.80;
    if (madeSelection == 5) ans = val * 3.38;
    if (madeSelection == 6) ans = val * 1.25;
    document.getElementById("conversion").value = ans;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select name="converts" id="Selection">
        <option>Chose Option</option>
        <option value="1">EC to US</option>
        <option value="2">EC to Euro</option>
        <option value="3">US to EC</option>
        <option value="4">US to Euro</option>
        <option value="5">Euro to EC</option>
        <option value="6">Euro to US</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>Value
    <input type="text" id="value">
    <br>Conversion
    <input type="text" id="conversion">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="Button" onclick="Conversion()" value="Convert">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead a lot **IF** statements you should use **SWITCH**.

This is the right way

JS

```
function Conversion() 
{
  var val = parseInt(document.getElementById ("value").value);
  var madeSelection =  parseInt(document.getElementById ("Selection").value);

  switch(madeSelection)
  {
    case 1:
       var converted =  val * 0.37; //EC to US
       break;
    case 2:
       var converted =  val * 0.30; //EC to EUR
       break;
    case 3:
       var converted =  val * 2.70; //US to EC
       break;
     //ETC....
    default:
       alert('You chose wrong option'); // if user chose wrong option, send him message
       break;           
  } 

  document.getElementById ("conversion").value = converted;
  return false; //prevent for submit form
}
```

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1cdkvpms/